# Operation failed: can't delete an entity from database

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship

I have these method classes:

```
public class Links
{
    [Key]
    public int LID { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public virtual int RessourceId { get; set; }
}

public class Ressource
{
    [Key]
    public int RessourceId { get; set; }
    public string TitreR { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    //public int Position { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual int SectionId { get; set; }
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Links> Links { get; set; }

}

public class Section
{
    [Key]
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public string Titre { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tags> Tags { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Ressource> Ressources { get; set; }
    //public Section() { this.Tag=new List<string>(); }
}
```

And when I want to delete a Ressource, I have this error:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

error line:

```
_db.Entry(R).State = EntityState.Deleted;
_db.SaveChanges();    // error line
```

PS: It was working before I added the Filename attribute to the Links class... Any idea how to solve it? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make foreign key nullable (i.e. change it's type from `int` to `int?`):

```
public virtual int? RessourceId { get; set; }
```

That means you can have links without resource.

Comment: Thank you, it worked but I didnt get it, why it was working perfectly before I added this attribute? ( Filename)